# Check if an error has been written to the console

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to find a way to check if an error has been written to the console when running a cypress unit test.

I know how to log something to the console

```
cy.log('log this to the console');
```

but not how to check if an error has been written to it.

any suggestions how to read errors from the (browser) console log?

note: probably not the "smart" way to test but sometimes my js libraries which I use would "complain" and write the errors to the browser log. this is to simplify testing.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? I am still wondering how it could be solved. Thanks!

Comment: unfortunately not :| -> I also find it very useful as a general test after page load... not just errors, deprecation warnings as well...

Comment: That's true. We log some tracking information and that's what we want to assert. In Selenium we could simply use driver.browser.manage.logs.get(:browser)

Answer (score 36):

This does exactly what I needed of catching any error in the console and do an assertion of the logs count. Just add the following in `cypress/support/index.js`

```js
Cypress.on('window:before:load', (win) => {
  cy.spy(win.console, 'error');
  cy.spy(win.console, 'warn');
});

afterEach(() => {
  cy.window().then((win) => {
    expect(win.console.error).to.have.callCount(0);
    expect(win.console.warn).to.have.callCount(0);
  });
});
```

Comment: the simplest and clean way imho

Comment: use could try this module for cypress: npmjs.com/package/cypress-fail-on-console-error

Comment: getting an error: `[Function] is not a spy or a call to a spy!` in `window -then function(){}`. i copied the code verbatim. also tried putting the `Cypress.on` in the `before` hook, but same result.

Answer (score 35):

There have been some updates since the previous answers.

Because the window is re-created with each `cy.visit`, Cypress recommends stubbing as a part of the `cy.visit` command.

```js
cy.visit('/', {
  onBeforeLoad(win) {
    cy.stub(win.console, 'log').as('consoleLog')
    cy.stub(win.console, 'error').as('consoleError')
  }
})

//...
cy.get('@consoleLog').should('be.calledWith', 'Hello World!')
cy.get('@consoleError').should('be.calledOnce')
```

For more details see the official FAQ for stubbing out the console: https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq.html#How-do-I-spy-on-console-log

And the recipe repository: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/stubbing-spying__console

Comment: this looks really promising! thank you very much! I just have to find some time to take a closer look :| (please bear with me)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. That makes error catching quit hard, when you navigate through your application, because you need to recreate the error loggin over and over again. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Nevermind, just found this article. Method 1 is what I needed: https://dev.to/tylerben/catching-console-error-statements-in-cypress-1b4g

Answer (score 14):

> **Edit:** the following *does not* directly log to terminal when in headless mode, but it nonetheless fails the test on AUT's `console.error` and displays the error message indirectly, even in the headless terminal, which may be what you want.

I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but let's go through all the places where an output can be logged in cypress, and how to handle several cases.

#### First, an overview:

[image]

1. To log into the **command log**, you use:

   ```
   // from inside your test
   cy.log('foo');
   ```
2. To log into **devTools console**:

   ```
   // from inside your test
   console.log('bar');
   ```
3. To log into **terminal**, you need to log from within the Cypress' node process:

   ```
   // from within e.g. your plugin/index.js file
   console.log('baz');
   ```

#### How to log AUT's errors to Terminal, Command Log, and fail the test

(note, AUT here stands for **Application under test**, meaning your application).

I'm also using [`ansicolor`](https://github.com/xpl/ansicolor) package to make the error red-colored in the terminal, which is optional.

```
// plugins/index.js
const ansi = require(`ansicolor`);
module.exports = ( on ) => {
    on(`task`, {
        error ( message ) {
            // write the error in red color
            console.error( ansi.red(message) );
            // play `beep` sound for extra purchase
            process.stdout.write(`\u0007`);
            return null;
        }
    });
};
```

Note: using internal `cy.now()` command to work around Cypress' tendency to throw `Cypress detected that you returned a promise` when it (IMO) shouldn't.

(adapted from https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/300#issuecomment-438176246)

```
// support/index.js or your test file
Cypress.on(`window:before:load`, win => {

    cy.stub( win.console, `error`, msg => {
        // log to Terminal
        cy.now(`task`, `error`, msg );
        // log to Command Log & fail the test
        throw new Error( msg );
    });
});
```

Comment: probably my question was not clear enough... apologies. I need to know how to read from the browser console if an error has been written to it...

Comment: What do you mean by "read from browser console"? Read how, and where? What are you planning to accomplish? In my answer, when your app writes a `console.error`, the test fails and is logged both to Command log, and terminal (even in headless). That's not what you want?

Comment: I would like to "Check if an error has been written to the console", e.g. some lib throws an error which is logged in the browser console (simulated by `console.error('some error');`). so I am trying to check if there are errors written in the DevTools console.

Comment: I'm failing to understand how that differs from the code in my answer.

Comment: I tried to run your 2nd snippet in a test but I can't get it to work:
`
it('so', () => {
        // support/index.js or your test file
        Cypress.on('window:before:load', (win) => {
            console.error('some warning');
            cy.pause();
            cy.stub( win.console, 'error', (msg) => {
                cy.pause();
                // log to Terminal
                cy.now('task', 'error', msg );
                cy.pause();
                // log to Command Log & fail the test
                throw new Error( msg );
            });
        });
    });
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185850/discussion-between-dwelle-and-udo).

Comment: How to log AUT's errors to Terminal and **NOT** fail the test?

Comment: @van_folmert just calling the `cy.now()` and not throwing doesn't work?

Answer (score 5):

Currently there is no straightforward way to do what you are asking but there have been some good discussions on how best to get this information.  I copied one solution here but if you follow the github link you can see other solutions proposed.

This snippet was taken from the github issue found here:  https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/300

> Just FYI the one easy solution is just to spy on console functions.
>   `cy.window().then((win) => {   cy.spy(win.console, "log") })`
>
> That will print a command log every time that function is called, and
>   you could also then assert what has been logged.

Another option depending on why you want to assert that something went wrong is to print the error out under the tests in headless mode.  The VP of engineering created an NPM package that does this for you.

[Cypress-failed-log](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-failed-log)

Comment: thanks. how would I check that `console.error('some error');` has been written to the console?

Answer (score 1):

The most easiest way if you simply want to ensure that no error is in the console (which is the most usecase I assume).

```
# npm
npm install cypress-fail-on-console-error --save-dev
# yarn
yarn add cypress-fail-on-console-error -D
```

And then add to your support/index.ts file:

```
import failOnConsoleError from "cypress-fail-on-console-error"
failOnConsoleError()
```

Now your cypress tests are failing just in time when a console error is printed.

Comment: Various configuration options give you extra flexibility. Check out the readme: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-fail-on-console-error

Answer (score 0):

This is the working solution I currently use to check for console errors.

```
let windowConsoleError;

Cypress.on('window:before:load', (win) => {
  windowConsoleError = cy.spy(win.console, 'error'); 
})

afterEach(() => {
  expect(windowConsoleError).to.not.be.called;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for an alternative simple approach, this one worked for me:

```js
cy.task('log', 'Your message here');
```

Answer (score 0):

if somebody will get:

```
cy.visit from a component spec is not allowed
```

or is looking for simpler answer

```
cy.stub(console, 'log').as('consoleLog')

-- your code --

cy.get('@consoleLog').should('be.calledWith', 'your desired log')
```