# Cypress unit testing: how to check for script errors?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, cypress

Is there a way to check if there are any script errors in the JavaScript console after page load when testing with Cypress testing framework?

I know I can check for visibility of certain dom elements, but I was curious if there is a more generalized check?

Thanks

Comment: you mean something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53915574/927631

Comment: yes the question sounds like what I am asking for but there are no good answers as of yet

Comment: There's an [open issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/448), and a [workaround](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/300#issuecomment-321587149).