# Monitor console output of websites in Cypress.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, automated-tests, cypress

I am using Cypress.io to test our new application (Node, React), but I would like to be able to monitor and check the console.log output of the website for any errors that are not explicitly captured through our standard tests.

I am hoping that this will not only be used to capture stray console.log commands that should not be added to production-ready code, but will also capture deprecations and warnings from any of our dependencies.

Please can you let me know if this is achievable, and if so, how I would do it?

Thanks, Chris.

Answer (score 4):

```
  let spyErrorLog;
  before(() => {
    Cypress.on("window:before:load", (win) => {
      spyErrorLog = cy.spy(win.console, "error");  // can be: log, warn
    });
  });

  after(() => {
    expect(spyErrorLog).not.to.be.called;
  });
```

from
see here [Check if an error has been written to the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53898085/check-if-an-error-has-been-written-to-the-console)

https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq#How-do-I-spy-on-console-log
https://docs.cypress.io/examples/examples/recipes#Stubbing-and-spying

Comment: IMHO this is a better answer due to it being platform (browser) agnostic

Comment: Where should this code be placed, ideally?

Answer (score 3):

Check out this plug-in for Cypress that will print all browser logs to stdout:

https://github.com/flotwig/cypress-log-to-output

It only works for Chrome, so just make sure your CI is set up to use Chrome and you're using Chrome locally too.

Comment: Thanks. This appears to do half the job I need it too and I am not worried about it not working on the Elecron browser as our browser target is Chrome anyway. I will investigate this and see whether I can use this.

Comment: It should log everything, including browser messages, so let me know if it doesn't work as expected :)