# How to have Cypress go through every page on site to see if there are any console errors and if so, make it known to the user running the test

Tags: automated-tests, cypress, performance-testing, content-security-policy

I want Cypress to go through every page to see on a website to see if there are any console errors and if so, make it known to the user running the test. (I'm thinking it would be useful for CSP checking to see if the site is throwing a console error because of a domain not being whitelisted.)

Answer (score 1):

This package [cypress-fail-on-console-error](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-fail-on-console-error)
 may make it easier

**test**

```js
import failOnConsoleError from 'cypress-fail-on-console-error';

failOnConsoleError();

const pages = [ "/page1", "/page2" ]

pages.forEach(page => {
  it(`verifies the page ${page}`, () => {
    cy.visit(page)                       
  })
})
```

---

There's some interesting stuff on Cypress and CSP here

[Testing Content-Security-Policy using Cypress ... Almost](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/testing-csp-almost/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of Cypress functionality to achieve this. You could store the list of links in an array of strings, use Cypress Lodash to iterate through each string as a separate test, and use the `onBeforeLoad` callback within `cy.visit()` to spy on `console.error`.

```js
describe('Tests', () => {
  // Define links
  const links = ['/1', '/2', '/3'...]

  // Iterate through the links array using Cypress Lodash
  Cypress._.times(links.length, (index) => {
    it('validates site loads with no errors', () => {
      cy.visit(links[index], {
        // set the `onBeforeLoad` callback to save errors as 'error'
        onBeforeLoad(win) {
          cy.stub(win.console, 'error').as('error');
        }
      });
      // Validate error was not called
      cy.get('@error').should('not.have.been.called');
    });
  });
});
```

A good deal of this answer was [taken from this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65218352/11625850)

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to be specific about the errors that fail, try catching `uncaught:exception`

```js
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err) => {
  if (err.message.includes('Content Security Policy')) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false  // only fail on the above message
  }
})

describe('Testing Content Security Policy', () => {
  const pages = [ "/page1", "/page2" ]
  pages.forEach(page => {
    it(`visiting page ${page}`, () => {
      cy.visit(page)
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: This does not work for me for some reason. How do I format this code in Visual Studio? Do I need to put naything in support > index.js?

Comment: It works in my test. Of course, I'd need some details to help you out.

Comment: Everything is in the spec file.

Comment: If you want to see another example, check out this Cypress recipe: [cypress-example-recipes/examples/fundamentals__errors/cypress/integration/app-error.js](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/fundamentals__errors/cypress/integration/app-error.js)

Comment: I just want to go through one of my clients websites, such as https://gcms-guinness.diageoplatform.com/en-gb and have the test go through the pages to see if there are any console errors (I'm thinking it would be useful for CSP checking to see if the site is throwing a console error because of a domain not being whitelisted.)

Comment: Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err) => {
    if (err.message.includes('Content Security Policy')) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false  // only fail on the above message
    }
  })
  
  describe('Testing Content Security Policy', () => {
    const pages = [ "https://gcms-guinness.diageoplatform.com/en-gb", "https://gcms-guinness.diageoplatform.com/en-gb/our-craft" ]
    pages.forEach(page => {
      it(`visiting page ${page}`, () => {
        cy.visit(page)
      })
    })
  })

Comment: I Input two pages from that Guinness URL I shared with you in the code and both tests passed. Is there any way that I can know what the console errors were though?

Comment: There are no console errors on either of those pages! If there were, you could do something with them inside `Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err) =>`

Comment: By any chance, do you have a site I can use to explore its console errors? I just want to test to see this works

Comment: The Cypress recipe is a working example. You should also ask your client to give you a copy of their site that errors.